# arcpy function, variables, and classes outside modules

Tags: arcpy

arcpy is a package that holds different modules including the **init**.py.

When I look into general Python documentation, they mention that classes, functions, and variables can be defined inside a module, so a programmer can import them using:

from packageName.moduleName import funcA, varB, ClassC

But in arcpy, there are functions, variables, and classes that are not inside modules e.g. env, Intersect_analysis, etc.. Where are they implemented? Are they stored inside modules and ESRI links to them through **init**.py for instance.

I tried reading the code inside the arcpy package but it is not clear to me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to see the code behind the different functions, or wondering about how to implement various functions etc.?

Comment: Good question. From the user perspective, I've observed the following: from "from arcpy import mapping" (the mapping module contains lots of classes), "from arcpy import env" (env is a class of environment settings), "with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(params) as cursor:" (note the "da" for the data access module, an "enhancement" that ESRI threw in). All this to say that I doubt you'll find a consistent organization throughout arcpy.

Comment: Thank you Erica and Tom for your responses. Actually I am just wondering about the implementation or the structure not the code. When you look into general documentation of Python packages implementation, they recommend creating a folder (package) with __init__.py module along with other modules and the code is inside the modules. But it seems arcpy has different implementation!

Answer (score 2):

Esri software (e.g. ArcMap) primarily uses C++ for components in the software such as the Intersect Analysis tool.

The ArcPy library enables those tools to be executed as part of a script. The actual calculations and so on, for example when you run `arcpy.Intersect_analysis`, are still being done with the C++ based ArcObject Intersect tool.

ArcPy is a wrapper that enables Python access to those proprietary functions.

Comment: I see. Thank you Erica. I am going to teach arcpy in a workshop soon and just wanted to clarify this. so this means that Intersect_analysis is implemented in C++ "ArcObject" library and arcpy just points to it. Am I right?

Comment: @AhmadAburizaiza Yes; this is why ArcPy can't really run without ArcGIS also installed (although, I suppose technically it can, but you're not going to be able to use any of its functions).

Comment: Thank you Erica for the clarifications.